# How to apply shipping charge for guest user in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, php, shipping, guest-checkout, shipping-charges

In Magento 2 I have configured shipping charge of 50 INR for below 500 INR purchase and for above 500 INR purchase shipping is free. But I need to customize there is no free shipping for guest user. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you using Magento default shipping module or Custom shipping module ?

Comment: I am using the default shipping module.

Comment: which default shipping method are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

Inside this class `vendor/magento/module-offline-shipping/Model/Carrier/Tablerate.php` there is a method for price calculation with the name `**collectRates**`.

In this method, Magento will calculate the price based on the conditions that you provided. Override the function and change the calculation according to you.

Comment: I am using Flat shipping rate method

Comment: override this class for price modification "vendor/magento/module-offline-shipping/Model/Carrier/Flatrate.php"